# BUG - Election page overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It would seem there's a small bug on the election page where content overflows the container on the right side. At first, I thought it was intentional, because I like the fact that the summary boxes *stick out* a bit. But then I noticed the text was sticking out too. *I cut off the left part because I had already voted, and it's not really relevant.*

[[image: ]]
Click for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XGYL.jpg)

The bug is located in the CSS, where the `.election-page .post-text` is given a width of `635px`, lowering this to about `605px` does the trick.

```
.election-page .post-text {
    padding-top:  15px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width:        635px; //culprit
}
```

[[image: ]]
Click for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKpPy.jpg)

Comment: oh yeah, in the second screenshot the page is dark because I use a Dark Reader extension, it has no influence on the lay-out of the page

Comment: It could do with a bit more padding on the left too... 5px between the voting buttons is a bit tight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My name is Josh and I'm a Senior Product Designer at Stack Overflow. Thank you for taking the time to report this issue. Congratulations! You've uncovered a network-wide bug. I have pushed a fix for this and it should be resolved with the next production build.